# ADDS can't connect to domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using VMWare, Windows Server 2012 R2. I was just trying to create two servers, one where I created the forest and the other one to join that forest. There is no problem with the installation and configuration of the first server, but with the second server I have ADDS installed and when I want him to join the existing forest I have the following error : `Can not connect to the domain using the specified credentials. Provide valid information identifications and retry.`But on the first server I'm disconnected because : user is connected.

The configuration and a nslookup of the first server where I set up the computer's name, ip, dns, installed ADDS and created the forest **ert Test.local**

```
Windows IP Configuration

Hostname . . . . . . . . . . : ert-DC-01
Primary DNS suffix . . . . . . : ertTest.local
Node Type . . . . . . . . . .  : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled . . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy enabled . . . . . . . . : No
Search List DNS suffix.: ertTest.local

Ethernet Ethernet0 card :

Specific DNS Suffix connection. . . :
Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Network Connection Intel (R) 82574L Gigabit
Physical Address . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-CA-E5-32
DHCP enabled. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : No
Activated automatic configuration. . . : Yes
IPv6 link-local address. . . . .: fe80::80f5:4026:c972:dcf%12
IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.31.253.107
Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . : 172.31.253.129
IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 301993001
DHCPv6 client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2E-C0-D0-00-0C-29-CA-E5-32
DNS servers. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                   127.0.0.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Enabled

PS C:\Users\Test> nslookup ertTest.local
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server :   UnKnown
Address:  ::1

Name :    ertTest.local
Address:  172.31.253.107
```

The configuration of the second server where I set up the computer's name, ip, dns, installed ADDS and tried to "add a new domain to an existing forest"

```
PS C:\Users\Administrateur> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet Ethernet0 card :

Specific DNS Suffix connection. . . :
IPv6 link-local address. . . . .: fe80::403f:953a:205:ef92%12
IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.31.252.108
Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.31.253.108
Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . : 172.31.252.130
                                   172.31.253.129

PS C:\Users\Administrateur> ping 172.31.253.107

Sending a request 'Ping' 172.31.253.107 with 32 bytes of data :
Response 172.31.253.107: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 128
Response 172.31.253.107: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 128
Response 172.31.253.107: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 128
Response 172.31.253.107: bytes = 32 time <1ms TTL = 128

Ping statistics for 172.31.253.107:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate time in milli-seconds :
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

I hope I was clear in my problems explanations. Did I forgot something in the set up on the second server ?

Comment: `1.` The second server appears to have two IPv4 ip addresses. Why is that? `2.` I don't see any DNS servers configured on the second server. You need to configure the second server to use the first server for DNS.

Comment: I fixed the two ip addresses and installed dns server on server two. But I don't really understand what I need to add in it. On the server one I don't touch the dns server I thought It was automatically configured by ADDS installation, am I wrong ?

Comment: joeqwerty meant that you should add the IP addresses of your DNS server to your DNS configuration. Not install the DNS service on your second machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem exactly. Installed new server 2012, created a new forest, setup DNS, and setup a new domain admin. Setup second server, added computer to domain, pointed DNS at first domain controller, added domain admin to 2nd computer admins, and tried to setup the second node, got the same error.

My solution was figuring out the credentials it wants aren't the Active Directory user I created but the Administrator credentials of current computer. The DSRM password on the next page is what will authenticate it with the AD DS.